# Why does typeof behave in this way when assigned to a const variable?

Tags: typescript

Given the following code:

```
const person = { name: 'Joe', age: 25 };
type personType = typeof person;   
const foo = typeof person;
```

Why does `foo` evaluate to:

```
"string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"
```

It looks like an alias for `any` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't:

```js
const person = { name: 'Joe', age: 25 };
const foo = typeof person;

console.log(foo); // Prints: "object"
```

What you see is probably the *type* of `foo`, which is basically all possible return values of `typeof x` in JavaScript.

That's because `type personType = typeof person;` is evaluated at compiletime in TypeScript, but `const foo = typeof person;` is evaluated at runtime in JavaScript (see [`typeof` docs in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)). It's two different `typeof`s!

And this is not an alias for `any` because the type you are seeing says that it is a *string* with one of these values!

`"string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"` is the type of the `typeof something` JS expression.

(However, this makes me wonder why JS-`typeof`'s TS type is not conditionally defined based on its input. I believe it should be possible to do it in TypeScript, so I'm not sure why that isn't done already.)

Comment: Yep, it was the type of foo which I observed, it makes sense that it is the return type of typeof. Also did not realise there were two different versions of typeof. Thanks.